# NextJS Exports error, location not defined

Tags: next.js, next.js13, window.location

I have NextJS app, where I declare Pages to be client side using `"use client"` at the top of the file. When I try to build said application, I get errors stating

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
ReferenceError: location is not defined
```

and a stack trace pointing somewhere deep inside next.js and it's built files.

Example code in one of those files looks like this:

```
"use client";

function classNames(...classes: string[]) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

export default function RootTemplate({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const [navigation, setNavigation] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const { useSession, signOut } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const userNavigation = [
    { name: "Your profile", click: null, href: "/profile" },
    { name: "Sign out", click: signOut },
  ];

  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(false);
  const { session: data, status } = useSession();
  const username = data?.user?.name;

  useEffect(() => {
    setNavigation([
      {
        name: "Dashboard",
        href: "/",
        icon: HomeIcon,
        current: pathname === "/",
      },
      {
        name: "Users",
        href: "/users",
        icon: UsersIcon,
        current: pathname === "/users",
      },
      {
        name: "Organisation",
        href: "/organisations",
        icon: BuildingOfficeIcon,
        current: pathname === "/organisations",
      },
      {
        name: "Connection",
        href: "/connections",
        icon: LockClosedIcon,
        current: pathname === "/connections",
      },
    ]);
  }, [pathname]);

  if (status === "unauthenticated" && typeof location !== "undefined") {
    if (!(pathname === "/login" || pathname === "/register")) {
      router.push("/login");
      return (
        <>
          <Loading />
        </>
      );
    } else {
      return <>{children}</>;
    }
  }
```

What I was expecting was that the page would build as an HTML and would not try to prerender on the server as I am using `"use client"` directive at the top of the file.
Meanwhile it seems that nextjs is trying to prerender the page as is, and because `usePathname` hook from NextJS uses `window.location`, it fails to build.

I have solved this by checking for `location` being undefined in the only default state `status` can have when pre-rendering.

##### My question is: Why is `usePathname` using location that is undefined, when it is NextJS hook that should be able to work with this kind of component out of the box, without my ridiculous workaround? Or is my approach to this issue wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this could be to conditionally use `usePathname` only when it's available, like:

```
import { usePathname } from 'your-path-to-usePathname';

let pathname = '/';
 if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
     pathname = usePathname();
  }
  // Use pathname further in your code
```

Comment: That's very good answer, thank you.
I was rather hoping for someone to enlighten me why it works in this weird way when it is part of the standard NextJS library and should be able to work together with this standard NextJS setup.